# How to start using Jemmy 3?

Tags: java, user-interface, testing, jemmy

I would like to use [Jemmy v3](http://jemmy.java.net/) for GUI testing but I can't find any manual or user guide or even an examples of using it. I've found documentation only for Jemmy v2 and it looks like the library was completely rewritten and redesigned.

In Jemmy v2 I used:

```
new ClassReference(...).startApplication()
```

How can a similiar invocation can be done with Jemmy v3?

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what UI library you are using it for.

App execution logic may be and is different for different libraries: AWT, FX, SWT.

For JavaFX you would do it like this: `AppExecutor.executeNoBlock(TestApp.class);`

Comment: I'm going to use AWT and Swing.

Comment: You do not need Jemmy v3 if you are dealing with Swing. Jemmy v2 has everything you may possibly need.